# Constexpr loop with a no constexpr content

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-hana

I want to use boost hana to generate this final code:

```
template < typename ... Ts >
void  foo(Ts ... data) {

  constexpr auto tuple = hana::make_tuple(data...);

  //Code that I need to be generate
  container_c[tuple[0_c]].foo2();
  container_c[tuple[1_c]].foo2();
  container_c[tuple[2_c]].foo2();
}
```

container_c is a map generate at compile time, I'm don't think that it really matter here though. **foo2 is not constexpr**.

I was thinking using `hana::size(tuple).times` but I need an increment, probably using `hana::make_range(hana::size_c<0>, hana::size(tuple))` and I don't know how to do it.

I was hoping to find a function which will allow me to execute a function on each member of my tuple inside hana. Something like `hana::transform` but for void lambda.

I didn't expect to have some hard time finding how to do it with `Hana`, should I just use a specialization like in the old times?

*Btw, I'm using gcc 7.1 right now, but you can work on the assumption that I have no compiler restrictions.*

Comment: `hana::for_each`

Comment: @JasonRice how I wasn't able to find it in hana documentation... Thanks for the comment! But still a good idea to ask this, because I ended up with a even better solution (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate over your `data`, you may do

```
template < typename ... Ts >
void  foo(Ts ... data) {
    int dummy[] = {0, (container_c[data].foo2(), void(), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable.
}
```

Or in C++17

```
template < typename ... Ts >
void  foo(Ts ... data) {
    (static_cast<void>(container_c[data].foo2()), ...);
}
```

Comment: Note that [C++17 fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) make this a lot less ugly, if the OP's compiler supports them.

Comment: Seems like you want to initialize an array to iterate over? But I don't get this syntax at all. And the loop will be done at runtime then no? Btw I don't have any compiler restrictions, I will edit my question for that.

Comment: @hvd: Add C++17 version.

Comment: Oh I got it with the C++17 version :) Thanks, I did try something like that, I should learn more about fold expressions.